# Using UISegmentedControl to switch UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to switch between 2 uiviews by using a segmented controller but I can't seem to get the hang of it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
   contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.view = contentView;

   CGRect applicationFrame2 = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    contentView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame2];
    contentView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];



    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Player 1", @"Player 2", nil];
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(12, 100, 350, 30);
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [contentView2 addSubview:segmentedControl];

}

-(void) segmentAction {

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        [contentView setHidden:NO];
        [contentView2 setHidden:YES];

    }
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        [contentView setHidden:YES];
        [contentView2 setHidden: NO];

    }
}
```

When I run this code the Segmented Control doesn't show on any of the views. I tried taking out the line:

> [contentView2 addSubview: segmentedControl];

but now second UIView shows black instead of yellow and only the first UIView shows the UISegmented Control. I am a beginner at IOS and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in view didload.... remove this lines..

```
  [contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];
  [contentView2 addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

& add  following lines...

```
 [self.view addsubview:contentView ];
[self.view addsubview:contentView2 ];
[self.view addsubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: view added on main view...you add view in segment control....so that's why not display any view

Comment: And also, I had to tak out the line: self.view = contentView